# Cassandra .setFetchSize() on statement is not honoured

Tags: java, cassandra, datastax-java-driver

I want to implement pagination on the UI, so I set fetchSize like this:

```
boundStatement.setFetchSize(20)
```

But the setFetchSize() is not honored. My table has 400 rows as of now and all 400 rows are retrieved. When I retrieve the next set of rows using

```
rs.getExecutionInfo().getPagingState();
```

then the next 380 rows are retrieved. So the paging state is correctly set and retrieved, but why is the driver retreiving all 400 rows from the table and how can I avoid this or make it retrieve only 400

Portion of code:

```
....
....

// "SELECT * FROM abc.sometable"
BoundStatement boundStatement = pStmt.bind();
boundStatement.setFetchSize(20);

if (pagingState != null) {
  boundStatement.setPagingState(PagingState.fromString(pagingState));
}
ResultSet rs = session.execute(boundStatement);
PagingState nextPage = rs.getExecutionInfo().getPagingState();
int remaining = rs.getAvailableWithoutFetching();
List<?> list = new ArrayList<>();
for (Row row : rs) {
  list.add(getValidObjectFromRow(row));
}
 ....
```

Cassandra version - 3.7 and cassandra driver version - 3.1.0

Thanks!

Comment: How are you consuming the ResultSet?  It's possible the driver is paging the next 20 rows (and so on) under the covers.

Comment: If you use wireshark you can look at the queries/results and see if its actually fetching in 20 chunks or not. You may just want to add `LIMIT 20` to your query and manually page if want more control

Comment: Updated question with code block.

Comment: what version of cassandra are you using ?

Comment: I am using Cassandra version - 3.7 and cassandra driver version - 3.1.0

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`setFetchSize` controls the page size, but it doesn't control the maximum rows returned in a `ResultSet`.

```java
for (Row row : rs) {
    list.add(getValidObjectFromRow(row));
}
```

In the above code from your sample code, it will iterate over the first 20 rows, and when it reaches the end of the current results, it will fetch more until no more rows match the query.

If you want to limit the number of rows returned, you have a few options.

1. Add `LIMIT X` (where x is the number of rows you want) to the end of your query.
2. Only iterate until there are no more rows, i.e.:

```java
while(rs.getAvailableWithoutFetching() > 0) {
    list.add(getValidObjectFromRow(rs.one()));
}
```

This will read from the `ResultSet` until there are no more rows in the page, at which point it will stop iterating.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I went back and read the java driver documentation again and your response gave a new meaning to them! LOL :)